# Is there a max size to JMS message size in ActiveMQ "Classic"?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, file-transfer, activemq-artemis

All I could find is that there isn't a specific limit to message size, but it's dictated by the heap memory allocated to the JVM. Anyway smaller messages are better. I'm trying to send a 1Gb file with ActiveMQ "Classic" without running into out-of-memory errors. I've read that the guys using ActiveMQ Artemis managed to do 8Gb using 50Mb of ram, but it takes me at least 4Gb to send 1Gb (using the "blob" message from ActiveMQ "Classic"). Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried sending your large message to artemis [the recommended way in the examples](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/examples/features/standard/large-message/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/example/LargeMessageExample.java)? There, you'll find a `BytesMessage` is used (not a `BlobMessage`), which is what was probably used to back the 8GB/50MB [statement in the docs](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/large-messages.html).

Comment: I've seen that but we don't use Artemis, we are using activemq 5.15.2

Comment: Ah, OK. The question is flagged as Artemis and I only saw your quote about 8/50 on the Artemis site. Did you see it anywhere  in relation to AMQ5? Keep in mind these are two entirely different implementations of two different JMS specs.

Comment: My bad, don't know why i put artemis in there or if it did it by itself. What do you mean by "in relation to AMQ"?

Comment: That is, when I googled about the benchmark of sending 8GB using 50MB of RAM, I saw that in the Artemis documentation (mentioned above), but not in the ActiveMQ5 documentation anywhere

Comment: yes it's mentioned only on the artemis documantation